# Aquarists: What are we tagging questions about your tank's water quality?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm the wrong person to ask this, as I am completely inexperienced with aquariums, but I think I've caught something early that probably needs a standard.

We have 2 questions regarding aquarium pH and conditions, one with [water-parameters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-parameters) and the other with [controlled-environment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controlled-environment) (recently replaced with [water-parameters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-parameters) per below), both of which are not obvious and seem to mean the same thing according to the questions they're used on.

Is there a standard term aquarium owners use to refer to hypothetical tags [water-quality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-quality) or [chemical-balancing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-balancing)?  I think [maintenance](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) is too broad.

**We probably should be using whatever is commonly used in the aquarists (aquarium enthusiasts / fish-keeping) community.**

Can someone with appropriate experience or research please provide a proper suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been wondering about this. Getting water right is one of the most complex and frustrating parts of fish-keeping, so we're going to have a lot of questions of that nature. I just created [water-parameters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-parameters) yesterday because we need either that or [water-quality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-quality).

I don't think it matters which we use. The two terms mean basically the same thing and are used pretty interchangeably, and in practical terms typing "water" will show either as a tag option. But these are the two options really, unless we want to get really granular with [ph](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph), [nitrogen-cycle](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nitrogen-cycle), [water-hardness](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-hardness), etc. Strictly speaking, those are the individual water *parameters* that make up water *quality*.

One thing I've noticed, and the reason I went with [water-parameters](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-parameters), is that people tend to talk about *quality* when they have a problem with bad water and *parameters* when they have a question about good water. Like, "What water parameters do pearly danios need?" vs. "Why is my water quality so poor?" But [water-quality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-quality) is a more common and inclusive term, and for what it's worth, public aquariums usually have what they call a water quality lab.

Edit: I think the two concepts are so closely related, it would be confusing not to have them as synonyms. If we needed a level of precision that would distinguish the two, we should have a high-level [water-quality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-quality) and more targeted [ph](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph) etc. But I think that's overkill at the moment.

[controlled-environment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controlled-environment) and [chemical-balancing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-balancing) are not aquarist terms of art, so I'd vote no on them.  [water-chemistry](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-chemistry) is another option, but it's a little too specific: not all these questions will be chemical in nature.

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, your conclusion is: (1) use "water-parameters", (2) replace "controlled-environment" {for the instance it's currently used} with "water-parameters", and (3) if "water-quality" appears, don't make a synonym of it to "water-parameters".

Comment: I actually think water-quality and water-parameters are close enough to be synonyms -- sorry, should have been clear about that. So: 1. Yes, unless anyone feels strongly for water-quality; 2. Yes

Comment: You're saying this to the person who recently helped manage distinguishing "Feeding" / "Eating" / "Diet" ("Chewing" / "Pica" / "Biting"), so I'm a little sensitive to the distinctions between tags at the moment. :-)

Comment: Hah, well, these hairs won't split themselves!

Comment: I've killed "controlled-environment" for consistency; for now we'll leave this as a a W-Q vs W-P vs "terminology" open discussion.